# Dynamically Create Virtual Hosts with Rails, Nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, virtual-hosts

I really like Basecamp's idiom of "dynamically" creating custom virtual hosts for clients -- for instance, once a company has signed up they may quickly login to a special URL like:

```
https://mystartup.basecamphq.com/
```

--which I think is really neat, it segregates multiple organizations nicely within a single application. My question is: assuming I've got control of a given domain, is there an easy way to do this kind of black magic with Rails and Nginx -- that is, to dynamically create a virtual host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to do Basecamp-style subdomains in Rails](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/1512-how-to-do-basecamp-style-subdomains-in-rails)

Also:

- [Subdomain accounts with Ruby on Rails explained](http://www.robbyonrails.com/articles/2009/01/11/subdomain-accounts-with-ruby-on-rails-explained)

Comment: Very nice, up and running in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Most cases you are not truly creating a virtual host.  You created a subdomain one time that then accepts ANY sub-domain off of it and you pipe it to your back end for processing (404, 302, or 200).

do a search on "nginx wildcard subdomain".  The results from slicehost are usually very helpful.